# Is a Docker Container good for an application that runs 24/7?

Tags: docker, .net, containers

I have a .Net Core Console application that I need to run 24/7. I am trying to decide how to host this application. I am leaning towards hosting this in a Docker Container, as I may like to use Kubernetes in future to scale out to multiple instances of this application.

Are Containers designed for applications that need to remain active for long periods of time, or are they more for short running worker tasks?

Answer (score 3):

The most common response you'll get is 'yes' (and they "should" be), but as a sysadmin, I've had to repair broken docker contains after apt updates, for instance, too many times. This is not an answer per se, but some experience I can share.

Also, you may want to think about who's responsible for installing security updates and back-port security patches. A lot of containers are created then forgotten, leaving all kinds of vulnerably daemons, libs, etc. If you're running on an Ubuntu LTS, you are more assured of sustained security updates.

Also, when it comes to scaling; without knowing your situation, this is often taken as a requirement far too early in a process. Get some users first. You can scale up one server to dozens of cores, likely serving 100s of concurrent users easily. I see the mistake too much that "I'm making an app and I already know I will have a million users".

Answer (score 1):

Stateful Sets in Kubernetes are designed to leverage - as the name suggests - containerized stateful applications like for example Rocket.Chat (https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/helm-chart/), or other production applications that might have to have for example strict Recovery Time Objectives (https://portworx.com/kubernetes-data-management-perspective-understanding-rto-rpo/). So I say the answer is a definitive yes! Apparently using Kubernetes for a highly available production grade application is state of the art. I am writing my bachelor thesis about this and we do this at work.